# Use CodeIgniter to render to a view at a specific anchor

Tags: php, codeigniter

In order to delete a person from the database, I would like to check its connections with other objects like inventories before deleting then display a bootstrap dialog message within the same page.

Using CodeIgniter, I have a page named "Person's details" that has a link to check these connections like so:

```
<a class="btn btn-custom" href="person/checkConnections/<?=$ID_Person?>">Delete</a>
```

In the controller "person", the method "checkConnections" looks like:

```
public function checkConnections($ID_Person)
{
  $data["strConnections"] = "3 connections with inventories found";
  $this->load->view("person/showdetails", $data)
  // launch the dialog box #deleteMsg
  ???
}
```

How can I launch the bootstrap dialog box which has an id="deleteMsg" and which is in the "Person's details" page?
if it was an html url, the url would look like : http://mywebsite/person/showdetails/134#deleteMsg. But how can I have the same result using the codeIgniter method to render a view?

I can check these connections when loading the page the first time. But it wouldn't be efficient to do it every time since the delete action is rarely used.

Comment: Who downvoted this? It's a legitimate question! 

**How can I launch the bootstrap dialog box which has an id="deleteMsg"** - With Javascript. **The url would look like : http://mywebsite/person/showdetails/134#deleteMsg. But how can I have the same result using the codeIgniter method to render a view**? - With AJAX POST, return $this->load->view('whatever','',FALSE) and on your success callback, append/prepend/replace/whatever the view to the DOM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ajax to call the delete method and then show the response in a model form like below.

```
$('.btn-custom').click(function(e){
        var url = $(this).attr('href');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: url,
            success: function(rtn)
            { 
                //load the bootstrap model setting the rtn as html content.
            }
          });
        return false;
    });
```

the controller should return the html output of your view.

```
public function checkConnections($ID_Person)
{
    $data["strConnections"] = "3 connections with inventories found";
    echo $this->load->view("person/showdetails", $data, true);
}
```

note the third parameter `true` of the view load method, this will return the output of the view.